# Combine 2 SQL queries in order to avoid foreach loop

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to query a [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) database in order to get all the desired posts alongside with their images. I have managed to do it with 2 different queries. The first one, brings all the posts alongside with the desired fields and the second one, runs in a foreach loop in order to get the image for each post. My problem is that this takes a really long time and i want to avoid id. I need a solution in order to avoid the `foreach` loop in the second query and merge it into the first.

**Query 1**

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_posts";
```

And foreach returned posts.ID

**Query 2**

```
"SELECT wp_posts.guid IN (Select wp_postmeta.meta_value from wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = ('the returned post id foreach of ID output of the first query')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using normalization method it will solve your problem by avoiding two queries:

```
SELECT WP.guid
FROM wp_posts WP,
     wp_postmeta WPM
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  AND WPM.post_id=WP.yourForeignField
GROUP BY WP.guid
```

Answer (score 0):

I know in posgresql, a JOIN would do this. I don't know enough about word press, but I'll look into it and update this answer

UPDATE This should do it:

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts 
OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id';
```

The JOIN combines the two tables on a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress default function `get_posts()` like this.

```
$args = array('posts_per_page'=> -1,'meta_key'=> '_thumbnail_id' );
get_posts( $args );
```

[You can get more information from here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)